# Windows Forms - get Text value from object of type button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows form named `Form1` and panel within this form named `panel1`. I use the panel only to place buttons there so that I can group them and work with them separately from the other buttons in my `Form1`. For the purpose of my program I need to handle every button click made from the buttons inside `panel1`. For this purpose I use the same code snippet:

```
  public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Set a click event handler for the button in the panel
            foreach (var button in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {

                button.Click += HandleClick;
            }
        }
```

What I need to do is to have a way to identify which button exactly has been clicked. For this purpose I played a little bit with my handler method:

```
private void HandleClick(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("HI" + o.ToString());
}
```

which gave me some hope because I get this:

[image]

It's the second part - `Text: button4` which is actually enough information to continue with my work. But I can't find a way to get this piece of information without some complicated string manipulations. So is there a way to get this or other unique information about the button been clicked given the way I have written my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    private void HandleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btn = sender as Button;
        if (btn != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(btn.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would avoid using `as` if you do not compare its result to `null`. In this situation, an explicit cast would throw `InvalidCastException` if `sender` is not a `Button`, which is, well, more explicit than the `NullReferenceException` you will receive with `as`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi With OfType<Button>() i was pretty sure that the sender is Button, but you are right in general sense....

Comment: You're right that `sender` is guaranteed to be a `Button` here (assuming `HandleClick()` is not used elsewhere), but in that case, why bother with `as`? Use a plain cast since you're sure :)

Comment: Wont it throw an InvalidCastException in the same scenario with an implicit cast?

Comment: I'm guilty of using `as` in these situations, myself. Probably because it's more semantically meaningful. Though I usually handle the event with a `void HandleClick(Button button)`, attached with `button.Click += (sender, e) => HandleClick((Button)sender)`.

Comment: @Anon, what do you mean by *implicit cast*? If you're referring to implicit conversion operators, what they throw is up to their implementation.

Comment: Probably i have fixed it :), In theory you can attach this hander to a checkbox too, and the plain cast will broke...

Answer (score 3):

One option is to cast the object to a `Button`, but rather than doing the casting you can change how the event handler is assigned so that you don't need to cast in the first place:

```
foreach (var button in panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    button.Click += (_,args)=> HandleClick(button, args);
}
```

Then just change the signature of `HandleClick`  to:

```
private void HandleClick(Button button, EventArgs e);
```

Comment: Thanks Servy. Fast and accurate again. Really appreciated.

Comment: +1. This is my preferred approach as well. I usually just remove the meaningless `EventArgs` parameter altogether, though.

Comment: @Ginosaji I would if I didn't use it, but not knowing the implementation of the method I left it in.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast `sender` to the `Button` class so you can access its properties:

```
Button b = (Button)sender;
MessageBox.Show(b.Text);
```